# SQL Count columns from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have this view generated after using `LEFT JOIN` over 2 tables (simplified example).

Tables:

```
T1: Id, ...other columns not used
+----+-----+
| Id | ... |
+----+-----+
| 1  | ... |
| 2  | ... |
+----+-----+
T2: Id, NewId (Foreign Key from T1), Status, ...other columns not used
+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| Id  | NewId | Status | ... |
+-----+-------+--------+-----+
| 1   | 1     | 1      | ... |
| 2   | 1     | 2      | ... |
| 3   | 1     | 2      | ... |
| 4   | 1     | 3      | ... |
| 5   | 1     | 1      | ... |
| 6   | 1     | 1      | ... |
| 7   | 2     | 0      | ... |
| 8   | 2     | 2      | ... |
| 9   | 2     | 1      | ... |
| 10  | 2     | 2      | ... |
+-----+-------+--------+-----+
```

Current View:

```
SELECT
  T1.Id,
  T2.Status
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Id = T2.NewId;
```

*View:* (I got till here)

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Status |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1      |
| 1  | 2      |
| 1  | 2      |
| 1  | 3      |
| 1  | 1      |
| 1  | 1      |
| 2  | 0      |
| 2  | 2      |
| 2  | 1      |
| 2  | 2      |
+----+--------+
```

The required view needs to have separate columns for each status value (which are exactly 0, 1, 2 or 3). 0 & 1 are kept in the same column.

*Required View:* (But I need this)

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| Id | Status 0/1 | Status 2 | Status 3 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1          | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 2          | 2        | 2        |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

I feel like I missing something basic. **How can I get this view?**

I don't think we need Rank() stuff, and it's a big query over 4 normalized tables (in practice), which is why I need an optimal solution. **Subqueries work with inline `SELECT` queries**, but they need `JOIN`s as well. The production requirement has 10 columns for counts over 2 separate columns.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Status 0/1], ...` (Your input and results currently do not match your descriptions, though, so it's not clear that's what you're actually after.)

Comment: I have 4 normalised tables in prod which I need to join to create the first view, however, I want the required view in the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    id,
    sum(case when status in (0, 1) then 1 else 0 end) status_0_1,
    sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) status_2
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) status_3
from mytable
group by id
```

---

In your orignal query, this should look like:

```
select
    t1.id,
    sum(case when t2.status in (0, 1) then 1 else 0 end) status_0_1,
    sum(case when t2.status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) status_2
    sum(case when t2.status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) status_3
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.newid
group by t1.id
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the original table schema. Are you suggesting I should nest the complete JOIN query and then use the SUM/CASE syntax? Would it be possible to do so in the same query?

Comment: @AjitZero: I updated my answer to show how to do this with your original query. You don't need to wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when status in (0, 1) then 1 else 0 end) as status_01,
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as status_2,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as status_3
from t
group by id;
```

You should be able to build this directly into your `left join`:

```
from a left join
     b
     on . . .
```

Can be the `from` clause.  Or use your current query as a subquery or CTE.

Comment: I've updated the question with the original table schema. I'll try the FROM syntax in the meanwhile